# Present read email in screen

Tags: css, html-email, email-client

I'm not asking how to read SMTP or POP3. I'd like to leave this clear from the beginning. My question occurs with what happens afterwards:

I'm reviewing an old application that read email and presents it on screen using 2008's techniques. Nowadays, is there a css template that handles common mail templating in a twitter-bootstrap's fashion?

What's your experience in this sort of presentations?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "common mail templating" exactly?

Comment: Normally, when you simply echo an html email into your html view, you need to create styles for (at least) <bloquequote> to show every nested message with a padding in the left side. If I see my thunderbird raw message I can see a lot of moz-* classes. Outlook does the same with ms-* classes and God knows what other clients have their styles. That's why I thought there could be a css framework/library for that